# Elastic Beanstalk post deploy execute powershell script on windows server

Tags: yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new on AWS platform. I just like to know how can we execute powershell script (testing_script.ps1) after the deployment. Basically I have an .ebextensions folder and config files underneath it. But I don't know the right YAML code for executing my powershell script and I'm not sure the exact location on where to place the powershell script as well. Thanks in advance for your help

```
files:
  "c:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\ElasticBeanstalk\\hooks\\appdeploy\\post\\testing_script.ps1":
```